# Cannot play media on Acer Aspire One AO751h

Tags: performance, acer, media, aspire-one

I am having problems with playing media on my Acer Aspire One AO751h on Linux.

All media is laggy and jumpy, even MP3s and XVid-encoded video.

I know that the laptop IS capable of at least playing the MP3s because it works perfectly on Windows.

But even when running MPlayer in a VT with no other programs running, I could not play a simple MP3 file. It was too laggy to be listenable.

I have tried Xubuntu 12.04 and 14.10, and Lubuntu 14.10. None of the OSes I have tried can play media files at all except Windows XP.

All of the information available on the Internet for troubleshooting this (especially media-based problems) seems to pertain to the graphics drivers, but I'm already running the proper graphics driver (and that wouldn't affect audio, which is one of the things that won't play properly).

Comment: Before somebody asks, I have disabled Xv output. That didn't fix it (and wouldn't matter for the MP3s on the VT anyway)

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM do you have? I've always had the best luck with VLC on ubuntu. You will still need to make sure you have the restricted extras installed. Ubuntu doesn't come with the media codecs to playback a lot of stuff unless you check the box.

Can you describe what makes the mp3 unlistenable? can you also provide some system monitor screenshots during playback? This could be your audio drivers, and but I want to make sure your processor isn't getting slammed with the decoding first.

Comment: The CPU is under some load, but neither the CPU nor the RAM are close to maxed-out (htop confirmed).
When I say "unlistenable" it's very very laggy.. that's the best way to explain it. It sounds the same way it does when a computer is really really struggling to decode something (but that's definitely not the case since CPU isn't the chokepoint) (HDD isn't the chokepoint either because it doesn't play from /tmp any better)
And yeah, VLC was my first choice. But when that didn't work I had to try other players (and MPlayer is known for being good in situations like this)

Comment: I did remember the MP3 codecs

Comment: I just found out that if I force ALSA output MP3s play perfectly.

Comment: AAND it was actually the audio that was choking up video playback (PulseAudio is the culprit here). I can play videos now as long as I re-encode then with H.264 `-tune fastdecode` or XVid encoding, remember to force my video player to use ALSA output, and disable Xv video output.